# Display Fancybox3 with large content (width)

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, fancybox-3

I have an issue with fancybox3. If you have a bigger content width, e.g. 2500px, the display of the box proceeds not as normal. To see this fancybox you will have to scroll down.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="height: 800px;">
  <a data-fancybox data-src="#hidden-content" href="javascript:;">
      Trigger the fancyBox width 500px;
  </a>
  <br>
  <a data-fancybox data-src="#hidden-content2" href="javascript:;">
      Trigger the fancyBox width 2500px;
  </a>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="hidden-content">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  <div style="width: 500px;">
  ... some stuff ...
  </div>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="hidden-content2">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  <div style="width: 2500px;">
  ... some more stuff ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I've a codepen for this issue. Any ideas?
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQmgjK

Comment: why dont you use the `autoDimensions: true` option to automatically adjust according to the size of the content

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: I tried this option, but it doesn't work. Also I don't find this option in the documentation: https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fancyBox uses inline-block trick for vertical and horizontal centering. This is the best option for centering in the unknown, but unfortunately there are some drawbacks. By forcing extra wide content, you are breaking it.

You have several options, for example:

**Make content scrollable**:

```
#hidden-content2 {
  max-width: calc(100% - 80px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdmyRo

**Hide pseudo element**

```
.fancybox-slide.wide:before {
    display: none;
}
```

(You can set custom class name by setting `data-slide-class="wide"` attribute)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdmydo?editors=1100

Comment: the max-width did the job for me. Thank you very much!